# Can load page in iframe. Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to load a page in iframe but I'm getting this error:

```
<iframe class="frame" src="http://groovemp3.com/new-releases/"></iframe>
```

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://groovemp3.com').

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: nothing to do with the URL in the iframe as far as I can see- I can use that iframe in my (http, not https) site without any errors

Comment: does the error message indicate where the error came from? your page? groovemp3 page? some other iframe you're also loading?

Comment: not really. I can see it in the chrome console.. really weird, because it worked couple of days ago.

Comment: does your page use `postMessage` ?